# How to select all checkbox inside telerik combox on checbox Checked event?

Tags: wpf

I have on checkbox inside telerik combo control. If User click on "All" option from checkbox list then I want select all checkboxs.
checkbox values.
My Sample code is below.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox  Name="rcbDays" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding  MonthDaysList}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" >
       <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <CheckBox Name="chkDays" Content="{Binding DaysText}"
           Tag="{Binding DaysValue}" Checked="chkDays_Checked" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
       </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

```
private void chkWeeks_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here I want code for selecting all checkboxes.
}
```

Comment: Read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

The items that you bound the `ComboBox` to should have a property like `IsSelected`, then you should bind `IsChecked` of the data-template `CheckBox` to that. Then you just need to iterate over the source collection and set `IsSelected=true` on all items.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass // Whatever you may have called it,
{
     public bool IsSelected { ... }
     public string DaysText { ... }
     //...
}
```

```
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding DaysText}" Tag="{Binding DaysValue}" />
        </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
```

```
//In the handler that is supposed to select all
foreach (var item in MonthDaysList) item.IsSelected = true;
```

Of course the property needs to have [change notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

*(Also a note on usability: I do not thing that `ComboBoxes` should contain `CheckBoxes`, if you need multiple item selection use a `ListBox`)*

Comment: I had bounded checkbox to combobox and combobox has property IsSelected.

Comment: @user1228382: I am talking about the **bound items**.

Comment: I am new to wpf so i cant get your point. sorry but can you clarify it little more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take one more property isSelected as said by H.B.
add IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" to CheckBox tag in xaml file. Create one property in the appropriate class i.e. public bool isSeleted.......

When you get in to event chkWeeks_Checked() in this function get reference of the ComboBox item source like objList = (TypeCastYourClassType)YourComboBox.ItemSource;... Now the objList contains all checkbox items. Iterate through objList collection and get isSeleted property for each and every single item and that's done....
In your case

```
MonthDayList = (TypeCastYourClassType)rcbDays.ItemSource;
for(int i=0;i<MonthDayList.Count;i++)
{
    MonthDayList[i].isSelected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good discussion for **allowing multiple values to be selected in the telerik combobox.**
It uses **checkbox within combobox**

http://codedotnets.blogspot.in/2012/02/checkboxes-in-comboxes-to-allow.html

Thanks :)